how to get the row count of spreadsheet ce
I am using spreadsheet "jspreadsheet-ce": "^4.13.4" as the table component of my project, now I want to get the row count of spreadsheet. I have tried like this:
const rowNum = spreadsheet.row.length;
const rowCount = spreadsheet.getRowData.length;
const r = spreadsheet.table.rows.length;

both methods return 1 row, actually the table contains 2 row. Am I missing something? how to get the table actual row count?
